# text labels getting clipped on ggplot facet plot (clip = "off" not seeming to help)

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(mpg %>% filter(displ > 6, displ < 8, ), aes(displ, cty)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(vars(drv), vars(cyl)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = trans)) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

The bottom panel on the facet plot below contains a point with approximate coordinates `x = 7`, `y = 15`. The label is getting clipped for this point by the facet. You can't see what should be inside the parenthesis. I tried the `clip = "off"` argument, but it doesn't seem to be the solution to my problem. What is the solution to this clipping? I want to communicate to ggplot that if the facet overlaps a label, push the axis out some.

I should also mention that I want the labels to stay put where they are. What I really need is the axis labels pushed out when appropriate, and I can't manually do it for the actual plot under consideration. Because there's dozens of 'actual' plots, that change periodically every few weeks, then I rerun my scripts on all of them. The plots also very widely (orders of magnitudes) on the axis so expanding the scale by percentages isn't that viable either (to my knowledge, maybe there is a good way).

[image: facet clip]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(mpg %>% filter(displ > 6, displ < 8, ), aes(displ, cty)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(vars(drv), vars(cyl)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = trans), hjust = "inward") +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image]

EDIT, per OP comment: Or, if you want to keep the labels aligned, expand the x axis:

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(mpg %>% filter(displ > 6, displ < 8, ), aes(displ, cty)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(vars(drv), vars(cyl)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = trans)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0.1,0)) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

Comment: Sorry @Jon Spring I should've mentioned I need the labels to stay put and instead need the axis pushed out. Just added that to the original post.

Comment: Added another approach, using expand to widen the range of x axis to include 10% more than the data range (vs. 5% default).